# How to isolate devices on a subnetwork?

Tags: networking, router, hardware, switch

I am an electrical engineer working for a university. Our network infrastructure does not allow static IP. Only DHPC devices can be connected to the wired network.

I am responsible for an industrial measurement system located on the roof of the campus composed of several devices (ip-cameras, PC, ethernet sensors...). Most of these devices only have static IP and setting a hostname is not possible. Therefore I cannot connect them directly to our wired network.

What would be the proper way to connect this system on the campus network?

Comment: Why is this question down-voted? I don't really understand this ServerFault. Could someone help?

Comment: because its valid whoever downvoted, without leaving a comment Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: Well, I am not really asking for a product recommendation, but it seems understood that way. I have edited my question following your advice.

Comment: it wont make it better, home and enduser question are also off topic

Comment: It is not a home and end-user question. I work as an electronic engineer at the university. Our infrastructure does not allow static IP and all devices must have DHCP. What is wrong or that makes you think it's an end-user or home question?

Comment: then update the question that it is related to serverfault.com, it still sounds like an enduser question and still asking for product related information which is and stay ofd topic ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135584/discussion-between-nowox-and-djdomi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a device which can NAT network traffic. It will have multiple network interfaces, where one connects to your university network, and the other to your IoT devices.

The *public* facing interface (e.g. campus network) can use DHCP. The device rewrites packages so they appear to come from this device.

This can be performed by a wide variety of devices; in fact almost all home routers do NAT by default, so you can pick one up at BestBuy for 20$ or so - or you can use more or less any computer with software such as OpnSense, PFSense or the Linux distribution of your choice.

Comment: Yes, I am exactly looking for NAT. But most Level 3 switches don't provide NAT and routers are way too expensive. Last but not least I don't have much space in my enclosure. Network routers and lvl2+ switches usually have a 19'' form factor rather than compatible with DIN rail.

Comment: Routers can be picked up for 20-30$ almost anywhere. If you want industrial range, it tends to be more expensive, but for instance Siemens Scalance S-615 is powered by 24V, does NAT and is mounted on 35mm DIN RAIL. Costs 5-600$ I believe.